# Apache url rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to configure a specific url rewrite configuration I can't figure out. Just wonder if anybody can help

I need to rewrite http://city-business.domain.com/* to htpp://city.domain.com/business/*

I really hope that this is possible ...

Thank you, 
Pavel

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =city-business.example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://city.example.com/business%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```